# Typescript error when using React defaultProps with connect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add `defaultProps` to `MyComponent`, then wire that up to redux. To do that, I'm using `Partial<MyComponentProps>` as `defaultProps`s type. However, Typescript is complaining

> Property type `bar` is optional in `Partial<MyComponentProps>`, but required in `{ bar: number }`.

I'd like to figure out why this is happening, and what a good solution is.
Here's the code:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<MyComponentProps, void> {
  public static defaultProps: Partial<MyComponentProps> = {
    foo: "hello"
  };

  public render() {
    return null;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
  return {
    bar: 7
  };
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Typescript is complaining in the `MyComponent` part of `connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);`

Casting `defaultProps` to `MyComponentProps`, or having `mapStateToProps(state: any): Partial<MyComponentProps>` both work, but this seems like something that should work out of the box. `defaultProps` is an official React pattern.